# Java integer to byte

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
byte[] someArray;
int a,b;
.
.
.
a=123; (result coming from calculations, always 0>=a<256)
b=91; (result coming from calculations, always 0>=b<256)
```

now i want to do this

```
someArray[0]=a;
someArray[6]=b;
```

however i tried to convert in to byte to this i failed (getting all the possible error messages i think). also tried various snippets referring to integer to byte conversion.

so any idea?

**update**
this is what i get **java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "z"** when i try this *byteArray[0]=Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(bani.substring(2, 3)), 16).byteValue();*

Comment: Have you tried `someArray[0] = (byte) a`?

Comment: i updated my answer in order to invoke an exception

Answer (score 2):

`integer -> byte` conversion will result in  a compilation error because it might result in precision loss. [Documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

However, you can do an *explicit* cast:

```
someArray[0]=(byte)a;
```

Comment: "Cannot cast from Integer to byte"... Anyway, i play in a range from 0 to 255, i can't lose anything.

Comment: Compiler keeps you from making mistakes. So it forces you to cast it explicitly.

Comment: if i do so, the application compiles, but it crashes when it gets to cast.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that Byte is not `0` to `255`!
It is `-128` to `+127`

if you are aware of this, simply cast the values

```
someArray[0] = (byte) a;
someArray[6] = (byte) b;
```

But srround it with a check because java will cast you everything:

```
if(value <= Byte.MAX_VALUE && value >= Byte.MIN_VALUE) {
    //do the cast
}
else {
    //error handling
}
```

for example:

```
int i = 1300;
byte b = (byte) i;
//b will be 20 here
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to envoke a `NumberFormatException` you can parse the value like this:

```
Byte.valueOf(Integer.toString(value));
```

**Remember that byte is from -128 to 127!**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, <strike>there is no unsigned data type in Java. All of them are signed</strike> `byte` is signed data type and can hold values in the range `-128 <= b => 127`. Secondly, you need to subtract 128 from the integer value and then cast it to `byte`, just to get a value that `byte` can hold:

```
someArray[0] = (byte) (a - 128);
someArray[6] = (byte) (b - 128);
```

Comment: -1 By doing this, if `a = 1`, `someArray[0]` has the value -127, see http://pastebin.com/sMDMUycm

Comment: It's also not true that there's no unsigned data type in Java. `char` is unsigned.

Comment: @dnet You didn't understand what I am saying. `byte` cannot hold the values > 127 since it is signed. What I suggested is to subtract `128` from the integer value just for getting a value that `byte` can hold.

Answer (score 0):

In Java integral primitive types (byte, short, int, long) are always signed.

Hence a byte is always -128...127

You can convert an int to a byte by using casting

```
int i = 120;

byte b = (byte) i;
```

if you assign 200 to i instead of 120, then b becomes -56, assigning b back to i then i will remain -56 and not turn to 200 again.

This is because the binary representation of 200 is 11001000, and put these bits into a byte then it is interpreted as -56, putting this into an int again makes it into 1111111111111111111111001000

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how far the application you develop this for concerns memory usage :-). We have an API `Bytes.toBytes()` in [HBase API](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html). You can use this API to get a byte representation of a lot of types. May be you can use the reverse of it like `Bytes.toInt()` for converting back. As far i seen, no issue of precision loss or value change is seen.

You can download the lib from here [Hbase Lib](http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/hbase/hbase-0.94.11/hbase-0.94.11.tar.gz) .. Add the hbase-0.94.jar from the lib to your project.

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee no error for values above Byte.MAX_VALUE and below Byte.MIN_VALUE you could use bitwize operations to impose a max value:

```
public static byte toByte(int i){
    return (byte) (i & 0x000000ff);
}
```

This will ignore all bites above the first 8. Thus giving you a valid byte from any int (with the loss of the 24 highest order bits).

If you use this operation a lot this byte far faster than comparison and cast.